# Getting an inequality to prove multiplication of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

short question, I want to prove the following statement:

If $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $ b_n \rightarrow b $ as $ n $ goes to $ \infty$, then $a_n b_n \rightarrow ab$  as $n$ goes to $\infty$.
while proving this I want this to hold:
$$ \vert a_n b_n -ab \vert \leq \vert a_n b_n - a_nb \vert + \vert a_nb - ab \vert $$
but I can't seem to go there from:
$$ \vert a_n b_n -ab \vert \leq \vert a_nb_n\vert + \vert-ab\vert $$ (by triangle inequality) 
does anyone know how I can get the first inequality.

Thanks.

Comment: $a_n b_n - ab = a_n b_n - (a_n b - a_n b) - ab = (a_n b_n - a_n b) + (a_n b - ab)$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, now it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Due to @DanielFischer.

Key observation is that: $$ a_n b_n - ab = a_n b_n - (a_n b - a_nb) - ab = (a_n b_n - a_n b) + (a_n b - ab) $$

So that by triangle inequality:

$$ \vert (a_n b_n - a_n b) + (a_n b - ab) \vert \leq \vert (a_n b_n - a_n b) \vert + \vert (a_n b - ab) \vert $$

which is as desired.